# draw by request instead of drawing with specified fps

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

how can I update image by my own (when model changes) or system (when other window corrupted image) repaint request and not to use FPSAnimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern, with the controller having a timer that notifies the view(s) only when required. I generally prefer `javax.swing.Timer`, as the action event handler executes on the event-dispatching thread.

Comment: Oh, there is method repaint, question is closed :)

Comment: Excellent! Typically, if I implement the `Observer` interface, I'll have `update()` invoke `repaint()`, just as you say. [`RCView`](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) is an example.